# Getting path to php-cli without knowing if it's called php, php-cli or something else

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a script that needs php-cli but I have the problem that php-cli may not always be called php or php-cli when you call it on the command line. For instance I have a system where it's called php56.

So I want a way of finding the path to the php-cli binary in my bash-script programmatically without any input from the user.

My thought was to look through all the directories in the $PATH variable to see if there are any files that has the name *php*. And then run php -v on what I find and grep for "cli". A bit of a kludge but it works.

This is my code:

```
IFS=$':'; for i in $(echo "$PATH"); do
    php_binaries+=$(find "$i" -name "*php*")
done


IFS=$'\n'; for k in $(echo "$php_binaries"); do
    if [ "$(eval $(printf "$k -v") 2> /dev/null | sed -n 's/.*cli.*/cli/p')" == "cli" ]; then
        php_path="$k"
    fi
done
```

One weird problem I had was that I could not grep for "cli" in the second loop, it would not find anything. So I tried sed instead which can find the word "cli". So that is why I'm using sed in the second loop (maybe someone knows why grep doesn't work?).

My question is, this does work but it's not what I would call a good solution, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: What if there are multiple PHP versions/implementations installed on the system?

Comment: Moreover, it is unsafe to run all executable files from PATH, containing letters "php", with `-v` option (consider `rm -v`).